# How to include tailwind installed using npm?

Tags: css, npm, tailwind-css

Previously had Tailwind included using CDN. now installed with npm, all the 3 .css files are being included but I can't see the styles being used in my html document.

[Directory structure and link to style.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S37kN.png)

**tailwind.config.js** is like this:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**package.json** has tailwind css 3.3.3 included

All the paths to .css files of tailwind are correct (base, components, utilities and in network tabs can see their successful requests.

I tried checking links. paths. package.json and tailwind.config.js files. everything seems in order. why are styles still not being applied? I'm using simple CSS not SCSS/SASS.

Comment: did you import the css file in your `index/main` js file?

Comment: yes @HarshitT i did .

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this command:

`npm install npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer vite`

In `package.json`:

```
scripts: {
 "start": "vite",
 "build": "vite build"
}
```

Your `tailwind.config.js` should be:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["*"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

and Import style.css into html file like this:

`<link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet" >`

Comment: Tried this, it's not working. Same issue

Comment: Tried this, it's not working. Same issue

In Network tab, this is order of requests.
index.html
style.css
base.css
components.css
utilities.css
ws

This is in my style.css file: (all start with @)
import 'node_modules/tailwindcss/base.css';
import 'node_modules/tailwindcss/components.css';
import 'node_modules/tailwindcss/utilities.css';

Comment: kindly share your code using codesandbox.

Comment: https://github.com/AbdullahAhmadAAK/Portfolio-Abdullah-AAK is my code. I've changed index.html file only to include tailwind by importing locally

https://abdullahahmadaak.github.io/Portfolio-Abdullah-AAK/
you can view the portfolio here and see css not working